# Is it possible to retrieve timezone in which time was saved in database?

Tags: postgresql

I have column `start_datetime` which is of type `timestamp with timezone`. I insert data like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES('2014-05-28 13:20:00+05');
```

And select data like this:

```
SELECT start_datetime FROM tbl
```

And I get back this value (from SELECT): `2014-05-28 08:20:00+00`, which is same date converted to UTC, which is correct.

However I was wondering if it is possible to retrieve timezone (+05 in the example) from `timestamp with timezone` column type? I have to know in which timezone timestamp was inserted into database. Or maybe I have to store this data in a separate column named `user_timezone` for example and store timezone data there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All timezone-aware dates and times are stored internally in UTC. They
>   are converted to local time in the zone specified by the TimeZone
>   configuration parameter before being displayed to the client.

[Source](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES)

So if you need to know the source timezone or the timezone specified through an INSERT or UPDATE statement, you need to store that in a separate column.

The careful programmer will use either

- the full name of the time zone, like "America/New_York", or
- a POSIX format, like "EST5EDT".

Both these should be guarded by a CHECK() constraint or a foreign key reference. Documented cautions are in the same section linked above.

[This recent thread](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/BAY178-W3669708526DF1D0A97C3BAC4DA0@phx.gbl) on the pgsql-hackers mailing list has some good background on the problem.

Comment: One more question - is there postgres function to get timezone name from datetime string to insert data like this for example: `INSERT INTO tbl VALUES('2014-05-28 13:20:00+05',timezone_name('2014-05-28 13:20:00+05'))`? Or maybe some extension?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no dead simple way to do that with PostgreSQL. The expression `extract (timezone from current_timestamp)` will return an offset in seconds; `to_char(current_timestamp, 'TZ')` will return a string like *EST* (Eastern Standard Time).